# How do I COMPLETELY remove the header of a datagrid in wpf?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to remove the header of a WPF datagrid. I've tried:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
           <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

But that only changes the size of the content, but the grid still displays a row for the header.

How can I prevent DataGrid from displaying the header row entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `DataGrid`'s `HeadersVisibility` property to `None`

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None">
<!-- WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE -->
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I also tried  that. Same result: An empty row is displayed instead of the header. I need the header to completely disappear.

Comment: @CesarColl well it should work... you have probably some controltemplate created? could you show it in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Set the HeadersVisibility property for DataGrid

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Row"></DataGrid>
```

or

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None"></DataGrid>
```

Comment: I also tried that. Same result: An empty row is displayed instead of the header. I need the header to completely disappear.

Comment: This will definitely hide your DataGrid's column headers and if you still see something as column header then I guess you wrote a Style for DataGrid and there is some issue in that XAML style.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. There was a style that was assigning the Header visibility. Thanks Nitesh!